# Custom user attributes with devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, access-token, rails-api

I have created a new API using rails/edge and I'm using devise with the [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) which has generated me a user model.

My question is this, after migrating and adding new attributes to the User model how do I return this in the JSON response, currently being generated by devise_token_auth?

Comment: So far my best solution is to create a separate UserDetails model, serialize that then make a separate call to it after auth to populate the extra user data. Which does actually seem quite nice as it keeps the auth clean.

Comment: it should be returned in JSON response without any further configuration.

Comment: I don't see how that would be the case. By default devise adds a lot to the User model that also isn't returned in the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to to in order to permit custom attributes for the Devise model (e.g `User` model)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    # for user account creation i.e sign up
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
    # for user account update
    # where bank_name and bank_account are nested attributes in the User model
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, bank_attributes: [:bank_name, :bank_account]])
  end
end
```

[source of this solution](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/440)

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comment above. So far my best solution is to create a separate UserDetails model, serialize that then make a separate call to it after auth to populate the extra user data.

Which does actually seem quite nice as it keeps the auth clean.